# How to match for a space with TECkit

Tags: fonts, xetex, conversion, font-encodings

Trying to change an existing TECkit map for Sanskrit to eventually do what I want (Adding a first pass removing spaces after consonants in transliteration before the second and third passes converts my text to Devanāgarī) my current stumbling block is how do I match a space? The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=mytest]{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Something that stays. \textsanskrit{Something to be transformed.}
\end{document}
```

with a minimal `mytest.map` (`teckit_compile`d to a `mytest.tec`):

```
LHSName "UNICODE"
RHSName "UNICODE"
pass(Unicode)
"o" > "x"
"g" > ""
" " > ""
U+0020 > ""
```

gives me the following results:
[image: Example]

So while I can do something with letters, and define classes of them and so on, I still haven't found a way to match a space. I suppose there is a way to do it, but maybe there isn't?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done: (Xe)TeX treats spaces differently from other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping regular spaces (U+0020 or U+00A0) does not seem to work at all, but mapping other Unicode space characters does. It's not clear whether this would be helpful to you or not.

Since you're throwing away the spaces, it's also possible to make the regular space character an other category (catcode 12).  This would allow regular spaces to be mapped too.  I've made an environment called `\translit` which sets the catcode of space to 12 within it. Note, however,  that spaces within macros will not be mapped correctly.

Here's a full document showing some of the options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\ENspace}{\symbol{"2002}}
\newcommand{\emspace}{\symbol{"2001}}
\newcommand{\thirdspace}{\symbol{"2004}}
\newcommand{\mymacro}{This is macro text!}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=mytest]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newenvironment{translit}{%
\catcode` =12
\sanskritfont
}{}

\begin{document}
Something that stays. 

\textsanskrit{Something\emspace to\thirdspace be\ENspace transformed.}

The source text can also contain the space characters directly:

\textsanskrit{Something to be transformed.}

The next source line contains only regular spaces.

\begin{translit}Some more text to be transformed\end{translit}

But regular spaces within macros will not be transformed:

\begin{translit}Some more text \mymacro{} containing a macro\end{translit}

Some regular text.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Map file:

```
LHSName "UNICODE"
RHSName "UNICODE"
pass(Unicode)
"o" > "x"
"g" > ""
U+0020 > ""
U+00A0 > ""
U+2002 > ""
U+2003 > ""
U+2001 > ""
U+2004 > ""
```

Comment: Interesting. Actually I'm not planning to throw away _all_ the spaces, this was just some initial testing, as I was stunned by the fact the spaces didn't seem to be matched. Eventually I want to get rid of them only after consonants, for which I'll create a class in the map file. I wonder what the side effects of your solution would be, anyway, I'll play with it a bit.

Comment: @muk.li The same solution should work. E.g. you can add `"d " > "d"` and that will remove the space only after `d`. (And the map file can use a quoted space instead of the hex code.)

Comment: Yes, my first small experiment with this solution now looked promising. Probably one would at some point also change the catcode of the newline character and include it in the mapping file. Scary stuff. I have to see how it looks applying this to some real files, if it breaks anything.

Comment: @AlanMunn If spaces are to be just ignored, ``\catcode`\ =9`` might be an easier choice, requiring no map file.